# hide / show checkboxes based on user select input

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Stuck on trying to solve this.. I simply would like to have a static HTML form with checkboxes. Then the user hits the page then can select via the checkboxes, the checkbox or checkboxes that are selected remain on page, then ones that are not selected simply hide.

**Below is the latest logic I have tried:**

*(simplified version of 2 checkboxes, but note there will be 10)*

```
$('#cbxShowHide').click(function(){
    this.checked?$('#div1').show(1000);
    $('#div2').hide(1000);
});

$('#cbxShowHide2').click(function(){
    this.checked?$('#div2').show(1000);
    $('#div1').hide(1000);
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cbp4N/650/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="div1">
<input type="checkbox" id="cbxShowHide"/><label for="cbxShowHide">Show/Hide</label>
</div>

<div class="div2">
<input type="checkbox" id="cbxShowHide2"/><label for="cbxShowHide2">Show/Hide</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this solution

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
      $("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").parent().hide();
    })
```

```css
#block{display:none;background:#eef;padding:10px;text-align:center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="div1">
<input type="checkbox" id="cbxShowHide"/><label for="cbxShowHide">Show/Hide</label>
</div>

<div class="div2">
<input type="checkbox" id="cbxShowHide2"/><label for="cbxShowHide2">Show/Hide</label>
</div>

<button>
  Hide Checkboxes
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use :

```
if ( $(this).is(':checked') ){
    $('.div1').show(1000);
    $('.div2').hide(1000);
}
```

**Note :** `$('.div1')` instead of `$('#div1')` because you're using classes no ids.

hope this helps.

---

```js
$('#cbxShowHide').click(function(){
  
  if ( $(this).is(':checked') ){
      $('.div1').show();
      $('.div2').hide();
  }else{
      $('.div2').show();
  }
});

$('#cbxShowHide2').click(function(){
  if ( $(this).is(':checked') ){
      $('.div2').show();
      $('.div1').hide();
  }else{
      $('.div1').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbxShowHide"/><label for="cbxShowHide">Show/Hide</label>
  <br>
  div1 content
  <br>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="div2">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbxShowHide2"/><label for="cbxShowHide2">Show/Hide</label>
  <br>
  div2 content
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is have both items be classes, `.div` and `.cbxShowHide`, then do:

```
$('.cbxShowHide').change(function(){
    $('.div').show(1000);
    if(this.checked) 
        $('.div').not($(this).parent()).hide(1000);
});
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/cbp4N/656/)

Which will hide all the clicked items but the element you clicked on. And show the elements when you un-check.